# Class Loading Issue with HornetMQ and JBoss 7.0.2

Tags: classnotfoundexception, jboss7.x, hornetq

I am working on a JBoss 7.0.2 instance. Our app is a war and messages are dropped into the queue. This works fine. But when we read it via a listener, the system throws an exception. It is looking for a class which is present in the WEB-INF/classes.

I understand that the module classloader (if I am right it is HornetMQ) is not able to see this application class and throwing up. I dont want my application class to be part of the server lib. That class living within the war is the best place.

The exception is :

```
javax.jms.JMSException: com.yyy.TransportMessage from [Module "org.hornetq:main" from local module loader @238b8914 
(roots: /Users/xxx/jboss/multi/jboss-as-7.0.2.Final/modules)]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:191)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:361)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:333)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:310)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:103)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:603)
    at org.hornetq.utils.ObjectInputStreamWithClassLoader.resolveClass(ObjectInputStreamWithClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1574)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1495)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1731)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
    at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQObjectMessage.getObject(HornetQObjectMessage.java:158)
    at com.xxx.MessageReceiver.handleObjectMessage(NSMessageReceiver.java:72)
    at com.xxx.jms.JMSListener.onMessage(JMSListener.java:1540)
    at org.hornetq.jms.client.JMSMessageListenerWrapper.onMessage(JMSMessageListenerWrapper.java:91)
```

What should I do to make this work?

Regards.

ashok

Comment: Why don't you make an EAR deploy so you can split the app logic from the server code as EJB project for app logic and a WAR file for the presentation layer?

Comment: it is an existing app which is being moved from jboss 4.2.3 to jboss 7. that particular class is there in the web-inf/classes. how do i make sure this class is visible to the proper classloader.

Comment: i tried this workaround  https://community.jboss.org/message/599052 and it works. it is an unnatural workaround though.